# Team city pass value between build steps with powershell

Tags: teamcity

Im simply trying to pass value between build steps in TeamCity. Im currently using PowerShell.

My Powershell code looks like

```
    $guid = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.test' value='$guid']"

    echo %env.test%
```

When I save this step and then run configuration all I get is following error

**Warning: No enabled compatible agents for this build configuration.
Please register a build agent or tweak build configuration requirements.**

[Print screen of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvWeG.png)

When I remove usage of %env.test% (= last line) variable everything works fine, but the problem is of course that I cannot use this variable anywhere.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the list of undefined parameters if you press on lightbulb left to the Run button or if you go to the build configuration > Parameters page. You'll see there that env.test parameter "value is required". You need to define it (empty value can be used).